# How to search selected option of dropdown list using ctrl-f browser search?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, drop-down-menu

I have multiple select dropdowns on my page. I need to find the selected option of dropdown using browser's ctrl-f search since the form is very long user can't scroll every time to find the selected option.

But browser's ctrl-f doesn't search for selected dropdown value.

[image: drowndown on web page]

[image: ctrl-f search is not able to find the selected option]

Is there any work around for this in javascript?

Comment: its not possible in page view but you can definitely find in chrome dev tool's  element tab

Comment: It sounds like you should use a select filtering plugin such as Select2 or Chosen if you want to search within a select element. CTRL+F will not (and cannot be modified to) work

Comment: I think you'd need to rethink your approach to the user experience if you're expecting them to have to use CTRL+F to use your page.

Comment: Thanks for reply guyz!!! I just wanted to know if there is any workaround. It seems I'll have to find other ways to search the data.

Answer (score 0):

Further to Faisal's response in the comments, open Dev tools (I assume most people readin this will know but: F12 in windows) and use your CTRL+F there.

Now, you can't just search for "Design Only", you will need to find an appropriate attribute using xpaths, e.g.

`//*[@componentvalue="Design Only"]` or `//*[@class="select"]`

I would suggest to inspect the element first and look for an attribute you can latch on to then adjust the xpath find criteria accordingly.